# Scaling / positioning of image in different aspect ratios with js

Tags: javascript, css, math

I have a editor that I am able to pan and zoom a image inside its parent container. The relevant css properties are then saved to the database. I then retrieve this data and apply it to containers with different aspect ratios, I'm unable to determine the correct mathematical steps I should be taking to maintain the center point in the same place as it was when viewed in the editor.

My current code can be found here:

HTML

```
    <div id="image1" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1024px;height:512px;display:inline-block;">
        <img class="aspectimg" src="https://a6f3312a23ab685f6e6f-9ea624413c4a7a869715c1bc0ff8b650.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/2/10223/11_7_1682540039.0925_10223.jpg" data-width="1024" data-height="512" data-left="60%" data-top="92%" data-zoom="scale(1.75)">
    </div>

    <div id="image2" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1080px;height:1080px;display:inline-block;">
        <img class="aspectimg" src="https://a6f3312a23ab685f6e6f-9ea624413c4a7a869715c1bc0ff8b650.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/2/10223/11_7_1682540039.0925_10223.jpg" data-width="1024" data-height="512" data-left="60%" data-top="92%" data-zoom="scale(1.75)">
    </div>

    <div id="image3" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1080px;height:1920px;display:inline-block;">
        <img class="aspectimg" src="https://a6f3312a23ab685f6e6f-9ea624413c4a7a869715c1bc0ff8b650.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/2/10223/11_7_1682540039.0925_10223.jpg" data-width="1024" data-height="512" data-left="60%" data-top="92%" data-zoom="scale(1.75)">
    </div>
```

JS

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        let aspectimgs = document.querySelectorAll('img.aspectimg');
        aspectimgs.forEach(item => {
            applyImageProperties(item);
        });
    });

    function applyImageProperties(img) {
        const parent = img.parentNode;
        const parentWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
        const parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight;
        const editorParentWidth = parseFloat(img.getAttribute('data-width'));
        const editorParentHeight = parseFloat(img.getAttribute('data-height'));
        const editorImageLeftPercent = parseFloat(img.getAttribute('data-left'));
        const editorImageTopPercent = parseFloat(img.getAttribute('data-top'));
        const editorImageScale = parseFloat(img.getAttribute('data-zoom').replace('scale(', '').replace(')', ''));

        // Calculate the aspect ratio of the image and parent container
        const editorAspectRatio = editorParentWidth / editorParentHeight;
        const parentAspectRatio = parentWidth / parentHeight;
        const imageAspectRatio = img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight;

        // Determine the scaled dimensions while maintaining the aspect ratio
        let scaledWidth, scaledHeight, oldScaledHeight, oldScaledWidth;
        if (imageAspectRatio >= parentAspectRatio) {
            scaledHeight = parentHeight;
            scaledWidth = scaledHeight * imageAspectRatio;
        } else {
            scaledWidth = parentWidth;
            scaledHeight = scaledWidth / imageAspectRatio;
        }
        scaledWidthAfterScale = scaledWidth * editorImageScale;
        scaledHeightAfterScale = scaledHeight * editorImageScale;
    
        if (imageAspectRatio >= editorAspectRatio) {
            oldScaledHeight = editorParentHeight;
            oldScaledWidth = oldScaledHeight * imageAspectRatio;
        } else {
            oldScaledWidth = editorParentWidth;
            oldScaledHeight = oldScaledWidth / imageAspectRatio;
        }

        var left = editorImageLeftPercent;
        var top = editorImageTopPercent;

        var translateX = '-50';
        var translateY = '-50';

        // Apply the new CSS properties to the image
        img.style.transform = `translate(${translateX}%, ${translateY}%) scale(${editorImageScale})`;
        img.style.position = 'absolute';
        img.style.left = `${left}%`;
        img.style.top = `${top}%`;
        img.style.width = imageAspectRatio < parentAspectRatio ? '100%' : 'auto';
        img.style.height = imageAspectRatio >= parentAspectRatio ? '100%' : 'auto';

        // Apply additional CSS properties to the parent container
        parent.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        parent.style.position = 'relative';
    }
```

https://codepen.io/Nod00/pen/eYPoNZO

In my code, the first image is the same resolution as the editor. The 2nd and 3rd images, I expected the area above the eyes and below the jewel to be vertically centered but clearly am not achieving this result. I also foresee similar issues on images with a aspect ratio > 1 but with the left dimension. This to me implies that I am not compensating for how the container has grown.

I expected since I am using translate -50%,-50% that it would make top and left properties position the image by its center point. I also assumed that since I'm using percents for the top and left properties, the size of the parent container would be irrelevant.

Any help would be appreciated!